# How to align 2 divs inside one div container with CSS (see image)

Tags: css, layout, css-float, alignment

I am making a little layout width exactly 6 divs, and I tried various times to align it with float align, clear:both and changing height/width, but without success. I want something like this image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/j1jxX.png

HTML source:

```
    <div id="description">
    <div class="itemDescription"><!--Item 1-->
        <div class="imageDescription"></div>
        <div class="textDescription">
            <div class="titleDescription">Encontre pessoas</div>
            <div class="detailDescription">Encontre facilmente pessoas com um buscador inteligente</div>
        </div>
    </div>
        <div class="itemDescription"><!--Item 2-->
        <div class="imageDescription"></div>
        <div class="textDescription">
            <div class="titleDescription">Encontre pessoas</div>
    <div class="detailDescription">Encontre facilmente pessoas com um buscador inteligente</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS source:

```
#description {
width: 96%;
background: rgb(244, 244, 0);
}
.itemDescription {
padding: 8px;
border: solid 1px red;
}
.imageDescription {
float: left;
height: 72px;
width: 20%;
background-image: url(http://addons.opera.com/media/extensions/75/86675/1.0-rev2/icons/icon_64x64.png);
background-position: center center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
border-right: solid 3px black;
}
.textDescription {
float: left;
width: 70%;
border: solid 3px blue;

}
.titleDescription {
border: solid 3px brown;

}
.detailDescription {
border: solid 3px black;
padding: 10px;
}
```

here is my JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5xhQk/

Thanks too all you

Comment: The fiddle has the same layout as the image just a different appearance. What exactly is wrong with what you showed in the fiddle?

Comment: The yellow padding is not respecting their space...

Comment: Finished It!! See the results( i put rainbow colors only to detach it: http://jsfiddle.net/5xhQk/3/

Thanks for all the help :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use table to get what you want but if you really want to use div, you need to use float in every div. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/5xhQk/1/

```
#description{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}

.itemDescription{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 72px;
}

.imageDescription{
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.textDescription{
  float: left;
  width: 70%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-left: 0;
}

.titleDescription{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
}

.detailDescription{
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Oh and I dont understand why in your picture it is width 20% and 70%, what are u going to do with the rest 10%?

Comment: The 10% is reserved for the borders :/ I dont know how to use exactly the 100% of the width. If I make 20% + 80%, the div will break to next line

Comment: so is what i have what u want or not?

Answer (score 0):

Let me see if i got it, u want to align the `imageDescription` and `textDescription` in the `itemDescription`

Comment: Yes. I want to make a left div aligned to a right div. Oh, It's possible to make the width exactly 100% with the borders?

Answer (score 0):

Try somethign like:

HTML:

```
<div class="itemDescription">
    <div class="imageDescription ">
        Your image
    </div>
    <div class="cl">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="textDescription">
        some header
        some paragraph
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.cl{
clear:both;
}
.itemDescription {

    width: something;

}

.imageDescription {

    float: left;
    width: something;
}

.textDescription {
    float: right;
    width: something;
}
```

Comment: It work too, the with the 'clear:both' I dont need to use 'float:left' in the parent divs :) Thanks,